# Why is my navigation not working in React Native using Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

So, I am trying to navigate to **HomeScreen** on button onPress Eveent which is in my **Splashscreen** like shown in the image below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uNmE.png)
So, I have created a screen named **DisplayImage** and then added it to **Splashscreen** screen and then put it in the **App.tsx** file. So whenever i click on the Button nothing happens, sometimes, the App get's closed. Where am i going wrong in my approach, do I have to add  always in App.tsx file? Below is my code

DisplayImage.tsx

```
import {NavigationContainerProps} from '@react-navigation/native';
import React from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  ImageSourcePropType,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  StyleProp,
  ViewStyle,
} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import HomeScreen from './Homescreen';
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

// Removed unnecessary import of createNativeStackNavigator

interface AppButtonProps {
  onPress: () => void;
  title: string;
}

const AppButton: React.FC<AppButtonProps> = ({onPress, title}) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={styles.appButtonContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.appButtonText}>{title}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

interface DisplayImageProps {
  source: ImageSourcePropType;
  style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
}

const DisplayImage: React.FC<DisplayImageProps> = ({source, style}) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.imageContainer, style]}>
      <Image source={source} style={styles.image} />
      <View style={styles.spacer} />
      <AppButton title="Hey there!" onPress={() => NavigationDone} />
    </View>
  );
};

const NavigationDone: React.FC<NavigationContainerProps> = ({}) => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageContainer: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 100,
    marginTop: 200,
  },
  image: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  appButtonContainer: {
    elevation: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#009688',
    borderRadius: 10,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 12,
  },
  appButtonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#fff',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
  },
  spacer: {
    height: 50,
  },
});

export default DisplayImage;
```

SplashScreen.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import DisplayImage from './DisplayImage';

const SplashScreen = () => {
  return <DisplayImage source={require('../images/cherry.png')} />;
};

export default SplashScreen;
```

HomeScreen

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import SplashScreen from './src/screens/Splashscreen';

function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safe}>
      <SplashScreen />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  safe: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Take a look at the basics of navigation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To switch screens in React Native, you must use the navigation.navigate or navigation.push method.

There few mistakes here and after some research, I am finallty able to achieve it in following manner.

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import SplashScreen from './src/screens/SplashScreen';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
function App(): React.JSX.Element {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

DisplayImage.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  ImageSourcePropType,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  StyleProp,
  ViewStyle,
} from 'react-native';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

// Removed unnecessary import of createNativeStackNavigator

interface AppButtonProps {
  onPress: () => void;
  title: string;
}

const AppButton: React.FC<AppButtonProps> = ({onPress, title}) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={styles.appButtonContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.appButtonText}>{title}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);

interface DisplayImageProps {
  source: ImageSourcePropType;
  style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
}

const DisplayImage: React.FC<DisplayImageProps> = ({source, style}) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View style={[styles.imageContainer, style]}>
      <Image source={source} style={styles.image} />
      <View style={styles.spacer} />
      <AppButton
        title="Hey there!"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home' as never)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageContainer: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 100,
    marginTop: 200,
  },
  image: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  appButtonContainer: {
    elevation: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#009688',
    borderRadius: 10,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 12,
  },
  appButtonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#fff',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
  },
  spacer: {
    height: 50,
  },
});

export default DisplayImage;
```

Now we would be able to navigate from one screen to another.

Comment: It's giving error in the line const GotoHome.. GotoHome is showing error

Comment: I finally solved the error! I updated the answer, so check it out and I hope it works well on your computer too.

Comment: import SplashScreen from './Displayscreen'; this is a mistake in App.tsx file. I have called DisplayImage in Splashscreen file, so I think it should give path of Splashscreen file instead of DiplsyImage

Comment: That's right. Try it that way.

Comment: I have made few changes in your answer and now I am able to achieve what I want. thank you